# Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

I'm working on a Cordova application which is using ajax. My problem is that in debug, the app is working. But when I build a release, I got the error :

```
{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'https://sub.domain.tld'."}
```

I don't understand from where is it coming. 
I added required lines to the res/xml/config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
<access uri="*" subdomains="true" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
```

And the permission INTERNET in the AndroidManifest. But the error is still happening...

And oh, here is my ajax call:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax(
            {
                accepts: {
                    xml: "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1",
                    text: "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1"
                }
                , converters: {
                "text xml": jQuery.parseXML
            }
                , type: "POST"
                //, contentType: "text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1"
                , contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=iso-8859-1"
                , url: address
                , async: false
                , cache: false
                , crossDomain: false
                , data: msg
                , dataType: "text"
                , global: false
                , ifModified: false
                , username: this.params.server.login
                , password: this.params.server.pass
                , timeout: 500000
                , beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
                    jqXHR.overrideMimeType('text/xml;charset=iso-8859-1');

                    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
                    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, HEAD");
                }
            }
        )
```

Hope you'll be able to help me find a solution.

Comment: `jQuery.support.cors = true;` - why are you overriding jQuery's cors detection? If a browser doesn't support cors, then telling jQuery it does won't help with anything.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-*` are *response* headers, sent *by* the server. Sending these headers in your request may be what's ruining your request. I have limited experience with Cordova's cross-origin behavior, though, so I don't know for sure.

Comment: I added Jquery.support.cors and the 3 lasts setRequestHeader when I had my problem. It wasn't working before.

Comment: Does it work without the async option set to false?

Answer (score -1):

The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) states:

> Returning false in the beforeSend function will cancel the request

Since your `beforeSend` function doesn't have a return statement it will return `undefined` which is falsy. I assume that cancels your request (even though I didn't test it). Try returning `true` at the end of your `beforeSend` function.

Comment: But it works perfectly in debug mode... The problem you are describing must cause the problem in both cases.

Comment: That's true. I should read more carefully :-) Hope you'll find a solution.

Comment: Thanks, I hope too. I will do has you said, it might avoid an possible future bug.