# Including HTML page within HTML Page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am including a HTML page, named test.html in a webpage. As below:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>load demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<b>Content I want to Include is here: </b>
<div id="success"></div>


<script>
$( "#success" ).load( "test.html", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status == "error" ) {
    var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
    $( "#success" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I get an error reading:

```
Sorry but there was an error: 0 NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file://machd/.../HTML/test.html'.
```

What does this error mean? And how best to solve it?

Comment: Does this [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453213/failed-to-execute-send-on-xmlhttprequest) help?

Comment: You need a server to make ajax work. 
Try xampp or similar solutions if you haven't got one

Comment: Local files ('file://...') tend not to work for xhr applications, try a local dev server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am in agreement with swornabsent and monxas above.

This code works without issue when uploaded and the page viewed on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of **Angular js** for including another HTML file

Read docs here

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

Example:

```
<div class="container">
  <div ng-include="'filename.htm'"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

- Give the absolute path to test.html as argument and debug

Answer (score 0):

The only browser which allowed ajax requests through file:// protocol was old IE and was remove due to security issues. Your code will work fine on any web server such as XAMPP, or UWAMP. simply run Uwamp, put yout project to www folder and open http://localhost

Answer (score 0):

the easy way...

1> Add the js file and include code

```
    <script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>

    <script> w3IncludeHTML();</script>
```

2> Just call your html file like example

```
    <div w3-include-html="h1.html"></div>
```